# Strange symptoms after Drupal 8 core update

Tags: updating

I'm new to Drupal 8.

After updating D8 Core to 8.3.2 when I try to access Block Configuration Page, I get this error:

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "entity.block.disable" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 190 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

Moreover, a new entered view path gives "page not found".

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the 8.x-3.0-alpha2 or an earlier version of the rules module installed.

Updating the rules module to 8.x-3.0-alpha3 or later should fix this issue too.